# How to programmatically detect whether rsync detected changes or not?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, rsync

If I do:

```bsh
echo 'sup' > sup.txt
echo 'nup' > nup.txt
echo 'sup' > sup2.txt
rsync -P --archive --human-readable --itemize-changes --dry-run sup.txt nup.txt
rsync -P --archive --human-readable --itemize-changes --dry-run sup.txt sup2.txt
```

both the rsync calls return exit code 0, which makes it difficult to programatically detect if there were changes or not.

What would be the best way to detect if there were changes using rsync, and exit as soon as the first change was detected (say in the case of a comparison of two huge directories).

I've tried piping to  `| grep -qvE '^>'` however, had no success, as both still return exit code 0. My thought now is that I could do `| grep '^>' |` and then pipe to something that exits 1 on any stdin, and 0 if no stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pipe solution I came up with `| grep '^>' | ifne 'false'`

So, the full code sample is:

```
echo 'sup' > sup.txt
echo 'nup' > nup.txt
echo 'sup' > sup2.txt
rsync -P --archive --human-readable --itemize-changes --checksum --dry-run sup.txt nup.txt | grep '^>' | ifne 'false'
echo "sup nup = $?"

rsync -P --archive --human-readable --itemize-changes --checksum --dry-run sup.txt sup2.txt | grep '^>' | ifne 'false'
echo "sup sup2 = $?"
```

Note the addition of `--checksum` as `nup.txt` and `sup.txt` in this contrived example could be the same date and size.

If you still care about stdout, then use `rsync ... | pee cat "grep '^>' | ifne 'false'"`

This code depends on [moreutils](https://rentes.github.io/unix/utilities/2015/07/27/moreutils-package/).